# Adiabatic elimination of the excited state for a light field beam splitter

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, two-level-system

I am going through the derivation of the eoms for a matterwave beam splitter based on Bragg diffraction from counter-propagating laser beams of frequencies $\omega_a$ and $\omega_b$ interacting with a cold cloud of atoms. I have come across the technique of adiabatic elimination of the excited state in these derivations which I am struggling to see the logic behind.

The derivation I am following is from this [article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1308.5205), I don't think it's necessary to go through every step but will give an outline of the derivation for context. It starts by considering a two-level system with motional $H_0$, internal $H_A$, and atom-field interaction Hamiltonians $H_{AF}$ such that the total Hamiltonian is the sum $$H=H_0+H_A+H_{AF}\tag{1}$$
The rotating wave approximation is applied and then a transformation into the interaction picture follows. The resulting Hamiltonian then acts on some arbitrary state
$$ \left|\Psi\right> = \int dp\left(g(p)\left|g,p\right>+e(p)\left|e,p\right>\right),\tag{2}$$
where $p$ is the momentum of the atom, $g$ is the ground state, and $e$ is the excited state. Applying the Schrodinger equation then results in the coupled differential equations
$$\dot{e}(p) = -i\Omega_ae^{i\Delta_at}e^{-i\left(\omega_{k_a}+\nu_{k_a}\right)t}g(p+\hbar k_a)
    -i\Omega_be^{i\Delta_bt}e^{-i\left(\omega_{-k_b}+\nu_{-k_b}\right)t}g(p-\hbar k_b)\tag{3}$$
$$\dot{g}(p) = -i\Omega_a^*e^{-i\Delta_at}e^{-i\left(\omega_{-k_a}+\nu_{-k_a}\right)t}e(p-\hbar k_a)
    -i\Omega_b^*e^{-i\Delta_bt}e^{-i\left(\omega_{k_b}+\nu_{k_b}\right)t}e(p+\hbar k_b)\tag{4}$$
where $\Omega_i$ is the Rabi-frequency, $\Delta_i$ the detuning from resonance and $v_{k_i}$ a Doppler shift accounting for the atom's motion parallel to the laser beams. The adiabatic elimination of the excited state then occurs and is justified by

> We assume the change of the population amplitude of the groundstate $g(p)$ and the frequencies $\omega_k+\nu_k$ to be much smaller than the detuning $\Delta_i$

which then allows for the integration of only the exponential terms $e^{-i\Delta_it}$ in Eq.(3), arriving at an approximate expression for the excited state evolution $e$

$$ e(p)\approx  -\frac{\Omega_a}{\Delta_a}e^{i\Delta_at}e^{-i\left(\omega_{k_a}+\nu_{k_a}\right)t}g(p+\hbar k_a)-\frac{\Omega_b}{\Delta_b}e^{i\Delta_bt}e^{-i\left(\omega_{-k_b}+\nu_{-k_b}\right)t}g(p-\hbar k_b),\tag{4}$$
they then go on to say that the approximation is only valid for $\Omega_{a,b}\ll\Delta_{a,b}$.

My question is, why is the assumption in the quotes valid and how does it relate to the approximation only being valid for $\Omega_{a,b}\ll\Delta_{a,b}$? And does adiabatic elimination have any relation to the [rotating wave approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_wave_approximation)?